# php function returning 0?

Tags: php, html, function, authentication, return

ok, so i am creating a php login system and wanted a simple way to get the link to the logout page by calling a function but it keeps returning 0. He's my function:

```
function logout_link() {
include("auth_vars.php"); //This file contains $auth_path_login
return $auth_path_login+"?status=loggedout";}
```

and this is how i am using it:

```
<a href="<?php echo logout_link();?>">logout</a>
```

However it keeps producing:

```
<a href="0">logout</a>
```

What is going wrong ?

Comment: What *exactly* does `auth_vars.php` contain?

Comment: Use `.` to concatenate strings in PHP, not `+`

Comment: Can't say much more without seeing auth_vars.php, but it looks like something in that file may return 0. Try moving the include to the top of the file instead of inside the function. Edit: @Pekka is right,  that's your problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The operator for string concatenation is `.`, not `+`.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: It's a common mistake; still happens to me sometimes when I switch from Java to PHP.

Answer (score 7):

In PHP `.` is the concatenation operator and `+` is either the addition, or the operator to merge arrays. Because you combine `+` with simple types (not arrays) PHP down-casts both values to a numeric value. In your case it's just `0+0`

Answer (score 6):

PHP uses `.` to concatenate strings, not `+`.

Try this instead:

```
function logout_link() {
   include("auth_vars.php"); //This file contains $auth_path_login
   return $auth_path_login . "?status=loggedout";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your PHP code is incorrect. It should be:

```
function logout_link() {
include("auth_vars.php"); //This file contains $auth_path_login
return $auth_path_login."?status=loggedout";
}
```

Comment: @luke: note the "." instead of "+".  The arithmetic operator "+" turns logout_link() into a numeric function ... which returns the result "0".

Answer (score 3):

You meant:

```
return $auth_path_login."?status=loggedout";
```

The concatenation operator is `.` in PHP.